# How do I track object value from Input decorator? Passing data from Parent to Child Component?

Tags: angular, input, angular-reactive-forms, form-control, formgroups

So I'm using Input decorator to pass data from `Parent Component` to `Child Component`. In the child component, I'm using a reactive form.

Now the thing is, in `Parent Component`, I'm using `NgRx store` to fetch data from and on basis of data availability, the reducer fetches data either from API or from the store itself.

If data is present in-store, all work fine, i.e. the form can be filled using the "patchValue" method manually.

But, if the data needs to be fetched from API, then things happen in an async manner and I don't have anything solid on basis of which I can fill the form again. i.e. I cannot track when I should fill the form.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution to this was pretty straightforward.

Now, Angular has something called lifecycle hooks, you can find the official documentation right below:

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

So, to track any changes for input properties, one can use `ngOnChanges`. Now when your input decorator values changes, the hook can be used to track the previous change and the current change.

*Tip to remember: `ngOnChanges` is triggered before`ngOnInit`.

Happy Coding :)